# bash script that receives any sequence of nucleotides and print all positions of the T nucleotides

Tags: bash, while-loop, grep, cat

I need to write a bash script that receives any sequence of nucleotides and print all positions of the T nucleotides.

I did the following:

'vim nucleotide.sh'
inside the script

```
#!/bin/bash
$@
cat $@ | while read line;do echo $line | grep -i t;done
```

But when I ran the script on new.dat sequence file

```
$ bash nucleotide.sh new.dat
```

it displays all sequences without marking T position, however when I run `cat $@ | while read line;do echo $line | grep -i t;done` outside the script, it displays the sequences with T colored in red.
Any suggestions, please

Comment: Are you looking for `grep --color-always`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the second line in your script is supposed to do

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for the 't' in the input, you can feed it directly to 'grep', no need to use bash `while read ... ; echo ...`, or even the `cat`. You can use grep `-h` or `--no-filename` to eliminate file name (in case multiple file names are provided)

```
grep --color=always -i t -- "$@"
# OR
cat "$@" | grep --color-always -i -t
# OR
grep --color-always -h -i t -- "$@"
```